# PowerShell script can't see mapped drive when run as Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, credentials, mapped-drive

I have a script for backing up my database. It runs great manually from PowerShell command-line, but if I make it a Scheduled Task, it immediately "completes" with return code 0. This is on Windows Server 2016.

```
param(
    [string]$schema
)

$date = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss")
$dest = "z:\$schema\${schema}-$date.sql"

try {
    mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=$PSScriptRoot\mysql-backup-opts.cnf --databases $schema > $dest
    7z a -mx9 -sdel -bso0 "$dest.7z" $dest
    exit 1
}
catch {
    exit 0
}
```

Because it exits immediately, I believe it's failing to launch the `mysqldump` command.  The dump takes a couple minutes, so if the 7zip were failing it wouldn't happen right away(...?)

NOTE: The `z:` drive is mapped with different credentials because the destination computer is on a different domain.  I'm logged in as local Admin, and the Scheduled Task also runs as local admin.

UPDATE: Per a comment, I ran it with `start-transcript`.  It's definitely an issue with the mapped drive.  "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'z' does not exist."

Comment: Add Start-Transcript at the top of the script (and Stop-Transcript at the end), logging the output to a file somewhere, you should then be able to see from the output why the script is failing to complete

Comment: Ah- network drives won;t be mapped under the account running the task you'll have to deal with saving to another domain location as part of the script

Comment: @Scepticalist even though I'm specifically running the script as the same account I'm logged in as?

Comment: I would test to see if they exist.. With if(-not test-path zj:){new-psdrive -Name z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\somename\someshare }

Comment: You could bypass the mapped drive and use directly UNC path to isolate the issue (and, unless the UNC path changes periodically, just target the UNC path).

Comment: @thomschumacher If I'm creating the drive on the fly, I believe I would also have to give the Windows credentials for the other computer -- who I'm mapping it *as*.

Comment: Even if you;re logged in the scripted task won't see the drive. You need to map the drive or connect as part of the script. Which means yes, you;ll need to provide credentials in your case

Comment: It appears the best solution in my case is to simply use the full UNC path, per @P-L .  Thanks everyone

Comment: I've needed to configure the `EnableLinkedConnections` registry entry to resolve this issue before - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co